# Drag and drop with RecycleView: Non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android

I currently have my OnClickListener inside my `public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnDragListener`.

I am receiving the error 
    Non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context.

I am trying to rearrange the order in which my items are listed, as you can see it ain't going very well.

What is the best practice to be able to manipulate the list depending on the drag and drop/on click approach when the methods are inside the static class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually did something I didn't really wanted to do but it works:

When creating the holder object I stored the items view itself and not just a select few fields. I was then able to attach a listener on the view in the onBindViewHolder method via the holder object containing the view.